# Is there a robust method to prove the existence of reincarnation?

Tags: self, religion, prosocial-behavior, death

Is there a how-to to prove reincarnation?

And secondly, I would like to lessen bad action from the previous life. And how do I do that?

Comment: No more than there is a how-to to prove that 1 = 2.

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**
You are confusing belief or faith with a hypothesis.

**Background**
Instead of a methodological answer, this question might, perhaps arguably, be tackled better from a slightly more philosophical angle. Let's go through the relevant terminologies.

[**Belief**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/belief) is

> An **acceptance** that something exists or is true, especially one **without
>   proof**.

A related term is [**faith**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/faith)

> [F]irm **belief** in something [often in a **[religious](http://faculty.valenciacollege.edu/drogers/factopinion/belieffact3.html)** context] for which there is **no proof**

Indeed **[Reincarnation](https://www.britannica.com/topic/reincarnation)** is a

> Religious belief

And henceforth it cannot be (dis)proven. By contrast, scientific hypotheses can be disproven through **[hypothesis testing](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/statistics-probability/significance-tests-one-sample/more-significance-testing-videos/v/hypothesis-testing-and-p-values)**. A **[hypothesis](https://www.britannica.com/science/scientific-hypothesis)** being

> [An] idea that proposes a tentative explanation about a phenomenon or a narrow set of phenomena observed in the natural world.

Reincarnation has not been observed in the natural world. Instead, it is based on faith in religious belief.